# How can I find duplicate orders per customer?

Tags: sql

How can I query my SQL database and find all the duplicate orders where a customer ordered something more than once?

Comment: How about some hints about what your customer and orders and order items tables look like?

Comment: Voted to close. Not a real question.

Comment: Don't be quite as rude guys... The question is indeed not very clear, but he might just have a hard time explaining what he means in English.

Comment: @Josh: You being rude helps nothing.

Comment: @ASGmail: You would get better answers if you give people some ideas of your DB schema.

Answer (score 6):

Not a super clear question, but I get the gist of it.  I don't know what your database looks like, but your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT customer_id, count(*) FROM orders
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT customerId, productId, count(productId) 
FROM CustomerOrders 
GROUP BY customerId 
HAVING count(productId) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A platform, version would help.  So would a sample table.  So here is a sample orders table:

```
SQL> select * from orders;

   CUST_ID   ORDER_ID ORDER_DAT
---------- ---------- ---------
     1      1 25-FEB-09
     1      2 24-FEB-09
     1      3 23-FEB-09
     2      4 24-FEB-09
     2      5 23-FEB-09
     2      6 22-FEB-09
     3      7 23-FEB-09
     9      8 22-FEB-09
     9      9 21-FEB-09
     4     10 22-FEB-09
     4     11 21-FEB-09
     4     12 20-FEB-09
     5     13 21-FEB-09
     5     14 20-FEB-09
     5     15 19-FEB-09
     6     16 20-FEB-09
    11     17 19-FEB-09
    10     18 18-FEB-09
     7     19 19-FEB-09
     7     20 18-FEB-09
     7     21 17-FEB-09
     8     22 18-FEB-09
     8     23 17-FEB-09
     8     24 16-FEB-09

24 rows selected.
```

The following select works on this table for a simple output:

```
  1* select cust_id, count(*) from orders group by cust_id having count(*) > 1
SQL> /

   CUST_ID   COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
     1      3
     2      3
     4      3
     5      3
     8      3
     7      3
     9      2

7 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a group by with both user_id and product_id.
Assuming your order table has columns user_id and product_id.

```sql
SELECT user_id, product_id, COUNT(*)
FROM orders
GROUP BY user_id, product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This gives the following table

```bash
user_id | product_id | count
---------+------------+-------
       6 |         36 |     2
      27 |         68 |     1
      31 |         39 |     1
      26 |         98 |     1
```

Postgres will first group by user_id, and then group by product_id.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [Select Distinct](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-distinct-sql-tutorial/) for it.